# Select rows where id is not linked to user in separate table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, one of users, one of cases, and one with links between users and cases. More than one user can be linked to a case. For example, assuming the user id in question is "18":

```
CASES

id  |  other columns
-------------------------
001 | n/a
002 | n/a
003 | n/a


LINKS

case_id | user_id
-------------------------
001     | 12
001     | 18
003     | 06
002     | 05
```

As you can see, case 001 has two users linked, one being our user "18", the other 2 cases do not have user "18" linked.

So the question is -
How do I select all cases where there is no link to user id 18? (results would be cases 002 and 003, since there is no rows linking those cases to user 18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT id FROM Cases C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Links L WHERE L.case_id = C.id AND L.user_Id = @userId)
```

Comment: When I tried to run this query it just hangs indefinitely. I also tried something similar, getting the count in the subquery where it was less than 1, and the same thing happened.

Comment: Are these tables extremely large and does the LINKS table have a proper index?

Comment: Links table is about 161k rows, cases is only 5,800. I have an index of the cases table but not the links table, since I am not sure how I can create an index of it.

Comment: Turns out I was on the right path from the beginning, but all the acceptable queries like yours were hanging due to no index on the large links table. Created a index for user id and case id and it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT` returns all cases, the `LEFT JOIN` gets cases from the links table that match and are for user 18, and the `WHERE` clause filters the joined rows out.

```
SELECT *
  FROM CASES
  LEFT JOIN LINKS
  ON LINKS.case_id = CASES.id
  AND LINKS.user_id = 18
WHERE LINKS.case_id IS NULL
```

Consider adding a compound index on LINKS with the columns ('case_id', 'user_id'). Assuming it's unique, you could make this your primary key.

Comment: I need to select all cases where the user id 18 is NOT linked to the case id in the links table.

Comment: Your query's LEFT JOIN makes sense, including dismissing records with user_id using `WHERE LINKS.case_id IS NULL`

Comment: @Evan, this query returns all cases that are `NOT` linked to user 18, as asked. It gets all the cases, then throws the ones that are linked to user 18 away.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a refactored query that gathers keys first before connecting to the CASES table:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT CaseIDs.case_id id FROM
    (SELECT id case_id FROM CASES) CaseIDs
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT case_id FROM LINKS WHERE user_id = 18) CaseLinks
    USING (case_id)
    WHERE CaseLinks.case_id IS NULL
) A
LEFT JOIN CASES B USING (id);
```

You will need a proper covering index

```
ALTER TABLE LINKS ADD INDEX case_user_index (case_id,user_id);
```

Give it a Try !!!